# Auto Slide JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was about to develop an auto slideshow using jquery, the logic was working perfect, but all the three div's in each slideshow weren't happening to see correctly. Could anyone help me with the code errors?

I need only 3 div's correctly fit into each slideshow. 
Would appreciate your suggestions.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container ">
  <div class="row ">
   <div id="carousel" class="carousel col-md-12 ">
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div1 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div2 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div3 Content</div> 
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div4 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div5 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div6 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div7 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div8 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div9 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div10 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div11 Content</div>
     <div style="width:324px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:4px;">Div12 Content</div>

   </div>  
  </div>    
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { padding-top:0px; border:1px solid green; margin:0px auto; width:970px; }

.slick-slider { position: relative; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
               -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none;
               user-select: none; -ms-touch-action: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; margin-bottom: 0px; }

.slick-list { position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.slick-slide { float: left; height: 100%; min-height: 1px; display: none; }

.slick-slide.dragging img { pointer-events: none; }

.slick-initialized .slick-slide { display: block; }

.slick-prev, .slick-next { position: absolute; display: block; height: 20px; width:0px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; cursor: pointer; background: transparent; color: transparent; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; }

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: "slick"; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; color: white; opacity: 0.85; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }

.slick-prev { left: -25px; }
.slick-prev:before { content: "\2190"; }

.slick-next { right: -25px; }
.slick-next:before { content: "\2192"; }


.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { color: black; }

.client-text li {left:0;right:0;margin:auto;list-style:none;margin:0px;z-index:9999;color:black;}

.slick-slide { width:300px; margin-right:0px; margin-left:4px; }
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $ (document).ready(function()
       {
         $ ('.carousel').slick
         ({
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
         });
       });
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/zteh64L5/1/

Comment: hard to tell exactly what is wrong. you say logic is working perfect, but also that the slides are not showing correctly. that seems paradoxical. perhaps it's just that there is a space after the $ signs before the parentheses in your jquery, there shouldn't be.

Comment: @hubsonbropa [White space is ignored in most situations.](http://jsfiddle.net/5dsajorv/) It is common not to have a space, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: hubson bropa - jquery functionality was working. I guess there was a problem in CSS, only the 3 div items weren't correctly showing. could you see any css errors. please let me know.

Comment: @apaul34208 ah thanks, learn something new everyday.

Comment: is there a special reason you don't just use carousel libraries such as slick or bootstrap carousel?

Comment: It seems the slick plugin and your CSS are conflicting. You're defining a number of elements to show in the plugin, which it then applies a style with the appropriate width based on the container width (I believe). However, you're also explicitly applying a width in the CSS (as well as an inline style) to those elements. Remove the widths, and allow the plugin to do it's thing, and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/zteh64L5/2/

Comment: Jack Pattishall - Thank you for your guidance. Its true that inline styles were disturbing because even width and height were also been defined externally. It was working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

By putting the margin directly in the slick-slide class you are affecting the plugin's calculations. You need to remove the inline styles in your divs and create a div inside the main slide one like this:

```
 <div ><div class="content">Div1 Content</div></div>
```

then in your css remove the contets of your slick-slice class' css and add this:

```
.carousel > div  >div > div .content {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:200px;
}
```

Check my modifications to your jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zteh64L5/5/